# Stylus not parsing block functions

Tags: stylus

I am using Stylus version 0.44.0...

I have simplified this example, but here is my issue:

```
color-all-the-things()
  div
    {block}

body
  +color-all-the-things()
    background: red
```

Is being compiled to:

```
body +color-all-the-things(){background:#f00}
```

It is essentially treating the block mixin like a selector.

The expected output is:

```
body div {
  background: red
}
```

Comment: Please add some information as to what you would expect the output to be. It's not a question at the moment :)

Comment: @d-Pixie I updated, let me know if that clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

According to the examples on the front page of the stylus project (http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/mixins.html#block-mixins) the syntax is as follows:

Mix-in definition

```
foo()
  .bar
    {block}
```

Mix-in use

```
+foo()
  width: 10px
```

Result

```
=> .bar {
     width: 10px;
   }
```

So in your case I guess it would be as you wrote it:

```
color-all-the-things()
  div
    {block}

...

body
  +color-all-the-things()
    background: red
```

Since that also produces the expected output in the online editor (http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html) we can assume you got it right ;)

All I can think of it check your toolchain. Make sure you have the latest stable release, or downgrade to one. Or if you do try upgrading to the latest development release. It specifically says that this feature is in a "rough state" in the docs so it's fair to assume there might be some problems with it in recent versions.

If the problem persists open an issue: https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/issues